# How could I return link to object property and not a value in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

Thank you for taking your time.

Here is my code:

```
right_field_return(player, player.what_to_edit) = message
```

This call raise `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` and I do understand it, but...

What does right_field_return does?
It is return objects field like this:

```
return player.current_mission.name
```

What I want to do?

I want to assign message value to player.current_mission.name

What do I get now?

Well, all I can do now is to return a VALUE from right_field_return, and I want to return a link to property player.current_mission.name - is there any way I can do it this way? Or maybe you can help me out and point in the other direction?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a setter method in your class that takes `message` as an argument and sets new value to `player.current_mission`